Installing NVIDIA RTX A5000 GPU hangs on Windows 10 on Proxmox using GPU pass-through
I’m installing an NVIDIA RTX A5000 GPU in a Proxmox virtual environment using GPU pass-through. The virtual is Windows 10 Pro. GPU card is plugged on HP Z640 Tower Server - Intel Xeon E5-2670 V3. I'm using proxmox: 7.4-17 version.
When the PCI device is added to the VM, attempting to install the driver recommended by GeForce Experience software the VM hangs.
I am unable to log back into the VM using RDP or VNC. The VM works fine when the PCI device is not added.
Note that we are trying to add the device when the VM is offline. The is device is not assigned to the host OS.
My objective is to pass through the GPU device to the Proxmox VM and install the corresponding driver. I tried Windows 10 Pro, Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server 22.02 but received same error.
Can someone help me with this?

You need 2 graphics cards for that.
